# Generate pair of columns of stores visited by the same client using a transaction dataframe and calculate aggregated metrics

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate

I have a dataframe with every transaction from multiple stores

df_transaction:

```
client_id   purchase_id   store   value
1           100           A       100
1           101           B       500

2           102           A       200
2           103           C       300

3           104           B       400
3           105           C       100

4           106           A       500
4           107           B       200
4           108           C       300
4           109           A       100

5           110           B       400
5           111           C       100

6           112           D       500
```

I want to generate all pairs of stores that were visited **by the same client**

df_pair

```
store_1   store_2
A         B
A         C
B         C
```

And then calculate:
How many distinct people went to both stores?
Total amount people in this group spent in store 1 and store 2?
Total transactions from people who went to store 1 and store 2?

The expected output would be:

```
store_1 store_2   count distinct both    sum_store_1        count_store_1    sum_store_2  count_store_2     
A       B         2 (client_id 1 and 4)  100 + 500 + 100    3 (client 1, 4   500 + 200    2 (client 1, 4)  
                                                               and 4 again)

A       C         2 (client_id 2 and 4)  400 + 200          2 (client 2, 4)  300 + 300    2 (client 2, 4)

B       C         3 (client 3, 4 and 5)  400 + 200 + 400    3 (client 3, 4   100+300+100  3 (client 3, 4
                                                               and 5)                        and 5)
```

Is there a way for me to do this? Maybe a self join with the dataframe I can create the dataframe with the pair of stores joining by client_id, but I'm not sure how to do that or get the count distinct, sum and count.

EDIT:
Quang Hoang query was working great, however now I found an issue with the Sum columns. If a client goes to Store A twice and Store B twice we generate a cartesian product and the Sum value will be duplicated in this example

```
client_id   purchase_id   store   value
1           100           A       10
1           101           A       15
1           102           B       20
1           103           B       25
```

The expected sum for Store A would be 25 and for Store B would be 45 but what we're getting now is 50 and 90.

Is there any way to avoid that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try self merge then `groupby`:

```
(df.merge(df, on='client_id')
   .query('store_x < store_y')
   .groupby(['store_x', 'store_y'], as_index=False)
   .agg({'value_x':'sum','value_y':'sum', 
         'client_id':'nunique'})
)
```

Output:

```
  store_x store_y  value_x  value_y  client_id
0       A       B      700      900          2
1       A       C      800      900          2
2       B       C     1000      500          3
```

---

**Update** named agg option that matches expected output:

```
(df.merge(df, on='client_id')
   .query('store_x < store_y')
   .groupby(['store_x', 'store_y'], as_index=False)
   .agg(sum_store_1=('value_x','sum'),
        count_store_1=('purchase_id_x','nunique'),
        sum_store_2=('value_y','sum'), 
        count_store_2=('purchase_id_y','nunique'),
        distinct_both=('client_id','nunique')
       )
)
```

Output:

```
  store_x store_y  sum_store_1  count_store_1  sum_store_2  count_store_2  distinct_both
0       A       B          700              3          900              2              2
1       A       C          800              3          900              2              2
2       B       C         1000              3          500              3              3
```

Comment: May be add `suffixes=('_1', '_2')` as well, to change the store suffixes

Comment: It's working for me, I just had to change the merge to df.merge(right=df, left_on='client_id', right_on='client_id', suffixes=('_1', '_2')). Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Hey Quang, the query was working great but now I found an issue with the Sum columns. If a client goes to Store A twice and Store B twice we generate a cartesian product and the Sum value will be duplicated in this example. Do you know how can we avoid that? I'll edit the question with this example as well

Answer (score 0):

Quang Hoang answer worked great for the count but for the sum it would duplicate values if a cliente went to store A more than once and also went to store B more than once

I had this in my transaction dataframe

```
client_id   purchase_id   store   value
1           100           A       10
1           101           A       15
1           102           B       20
1           103           B       25
```

And the self join would generate this:

```
client_id  store_1  purchase_id_1  value_1  store_2  purchase_id_2  value_2
1          A        100            10       B        102            20
1          A        100            10       B        103            25
1          A        101            15       B        102            20
1          A        101            15       B        103            25
```

The expected sum for value from store A is 25 and for store B is 45 but we would get 50 and 90

So now I'm calculating the sum for each one separately, dropping the duplicate values before doing the sum and then merging everything together

```
d = data.merge(right=data, left_on='client_id', right_on='client_id', suffixes=('_1', '_2')).query('store_1 < store_2')

g = d.groupby(['store_1', 'store_2'], as_index=False).agg(
          clients_both_Stores = ('client_id', 'nunique'),
          count_store_1 = ('purchase_id_1', 'nunique'),
          count_store_2 = ('purchase_id_2', 'nunique'))
    
gv1 = d.drop_duplicates(subset=['client_id', 'store_1', 'store_2', 'purchase_id_1', 'value_1'])\
            .groupby(['store_1', 'store_2'], as_index=False)\
            .agg(value_store_1 = ('value_1', 'sum'))
    
gv2 = d.drop_duplicates(subset=['client_id', 'store_1', 'store_2', 'purchase_id_2', 'value_2'])\
            .groupby(['store_1', 'store_2'], as_index=False)\
            .agg(value_store_2 = ('value_2', 'sum'))
    
g = g.merge(gv1, left_on=['store_1', 'store_2'], right_on=['store_1', 'store_2'])
g = g.merge(gv2, left_on=['store_1', 'store_2'], right_on=['store_1', 'store_2'])
```